# dask.bag.read_text s3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, dask

In my S3 bucket, there is a Directory & JSON File(without file extension) with the same name (surveyUUID) at the same level

**[1] "s3://data/surveyUUID/users/*.json" => Directory**

**[2] "s3://data/surveyUUID" => JSON file without file extension**

When trying to fetch **[2]**, Dask fetches the directory & its contents.

How to persist **dask.bag.read_text** to fetch **[2]**??

```
import dask.bag as db
import json
for uuid in surveyUUIDs:
    text = db.read_text("s3://data/{0}".format(uuid)).map(json.loads).compute()
    ## process(text)
```

**OR** get all surveyUUIDs, which also Doesnt work

```
text = db.read_text("s3://data/*").map(json.loads).compute()
```

Comment: Have you tried passing `"s3://data/{surveyUUID}/users/*.json"` (including the glob pattern) explicitly?

Comment: @mdurant I can fetch "s3://data/{surveyUUID}/users/*.json" completely fine. But I want to fetch "s3://data/surveyUUID"

Comment: Oh, I follow you! This appears to be a bug, we'll get back to you. For now, changing `db.read_text(uuid)` -> `db.read_text(uuid, blocksize=<BIG NUMBER>)` should solve this for you.

Comment: Thank you @mdurant Sorry if my question was poorly framed. I have made edits, I hope its clear now :)

Comment: Does using blocksize work for you?

Comment: @mdurant No, I get KeyError: 'ETag' after using blocksize=10000000

Comment: Curiouser. Would you mind pasting the exception/traceback and the contents of the dictionary that didn't include an ETag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120988/discussion-between-harsha-manjunath-and-mdurant).